# Python function+for strange behaviour

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement a multivariate gaussian pdf,

```
def multi_var_prob(x,mu,cov):
#Multi variate gaussian
  print x
  print (np.power(1/(2*np.pi),(len(x)*.5))/np.sqrt(np.abs(np.linalg.det(cov))))*np.exp(np.dot(np.matrix.transpose(x-mu),np.dot(np.linalg.inv(cov),(x-mu))))
  return((np.power(1/(2*np.pi),(len(x)*.5))/np.sqrt(np.abs(np.linalg.det(cov))))*np.exp(np.dot(np.matrix.transpose(x-mu),np.dot(np.linalg.inv(cov),(x-mu)))))

def get_multivar_pdf(y,mu,cov):

  for t in y:
    print multi_var_prob((np.matrix.transpose(t)),mu,cov)
  return
```

Now from command line

```
 >> multi_var_prob(np.matrix('2;4;5'),np.matrix('0;0;6'),np.matrix([[.3,.67,8],[2,3,8], [2,.05,2]]))


[[2]
[4]
[5]]
[[ 0.5179723]]
matrix([[ 0.5179723]])
```

gives the correct probability which is less than 1.

Now,when I use

```
  >>> l=np.matrix([[1,2,4],[3,4,5],[2,4,5]])
  >>> print get_multivar_pdf(l,np.matrix('0;0;6'),np.matrix([[.3,.67,8],[2,3,0],            [2,.05,2]]))

  [[1]
  [2]
  [4]]
 [[ 0.04517737]]
 [[ 0.04517737]]
  [[3]
  [4]
  [5]]
 [[ 1.13453039]]
 [[ 1.13453039]]
  [[2]
  [4]
  [5]]
 [[ 2.61451178]]
 [[ 2.61451178]]
 None
```

Its the probabilities are strangely getting added up and >1...But the in-going matrix is the
same.Please help.I use Python 2.7

Comment: Please point out the silly mistake I have been making...It would be grateful

Comment: what rough output are you expecting?

Comment: For a given matrix of vectors like 'l' in this program it should printout the correct  probabilities of corresponding rows

Answer (score 1):

- [The formula for the probability density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Non-degenerate_case) used in `multi_var_prob`
  is missing a -0.5 in the call to `np.exp`.

  ```
  def multi_var_prob(x, mu, cov):
      # Multivariate gaussian
      result = (
          (np.power(1 / (2 * np.pi), (len(x) * .5)) / np.sqrt(np.abs(np.linalg.det(cov))))
          * np.exp(-0.5 * np.dot(
              np.matrix.transpose(x - mu),
              np.dot(np.linalg.inv(cov), (x - mu)))))
      return result
  ```
- The covariance matrix should be [positive definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). A positive
  definite (real) matrix is symmetric, and has all positive
  eigenvalues. Yours do not:

  ```
  In [122]: import numpy.linalg as LA

  In [123]: cov = np.matrix([[.3, .67, 8], [2, 3, 8], [2, .05, 2]])

  In [124]: cov
  Out[124]: 
  matrix([[ 0.3 ,  0.67,  8.  ],
         [ 2.  ,  3.  ,  8.  ],
         [ 2.  ,  0.05,  2.  ]])

  In [125]: LA.eigvals(cov)
  Out[125]: array([-2.86046758,  5.96319816,  2.19726942])
  ```

  Remember that the elements in the covariance matrix represent the covariance of the variables, let's call two of them `X` and `Y`. Since `cov(X, Y) = cov(Y, X)`, the covariance matrix should be symmetric.
- Note also that `multi_var_prob` is returning a *probability density*,
  not a probability. The sum of the probability densities over the
  entire domain equals 1, but the probability density function may
  easily be greater than 1 at any given point. As an extreme example, consider the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). It's essentially infinite at one point, and zero everywhere else, but its integral (area under the curve) is 1.

Comment: Thanks unutbu that solved the problem but can u specify if the following value is sane??multi_var_prob(np.matrix('0;3;4'),np.matrix('0;0;6'),np.matrix([[1,2,3],[2,0,4],[3,4,7]]))
[[0]
 [3]
 [4]]
[[  1.60114334e-08]]
matrix([[ 44.70284829]])

Comment: Again, the covariance matrix is not positive definite: `LA.eigvals(np.matrix([[1,2,3],[2,0,4],[3,4,7]]))` shows the eigenvalues are `array([ 10.19615242,  -0.19615242,  -2.])`. So although `multi_var_prob` is returning a number, it is not associated with a valid multivariate normal pdf.

Comment: Also note, instead of defining this function yourself, you could use [scipy.stats.multivariate_normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) if you have scipy.

Comment: Ok now I see the issue thanks a lot for the answers..:)